# JSON to STL or other format for AutoCAD

Tags: java, json, stl, autocad, voxel

I have JSON file which consists of information about a building which can be constructed in a voxel based game. This file consists of a list of block types and their location with respect to a central block. I have to import this building into AutoCAD, how should I do this, maybe convert this into a STL or some other better file first? But all the resources that I could find online were doing the opposite i.e. STL to JSON.

Comment: A similar question can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17457571

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the `.dxf` file format to get the desired resulted. Since the JSON file already had the positions of the various boxes in form of a region's size and its starting block position, I just had to extract the position of each block from this and define each of the faces for it.
Used `3DFACE` for each of the cube faces
Reference : http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/dxf/min3d.html
An initial version of my implementation can be found on [github](https://github.com/Naman-sopho/PrefabToAutoCAD),though it still needs some tweaks to be finalized.